# Vue 2 About nextTick

Tags: vuejs2

I have read that nextTick allows codes to be executed at the next action. But this does not work in my code, can someone helps me on this? Please correct me. Thanks.

.vue

```
.....
methods:{
      getUserInfo(){
        var vm = this
        vm.$http.get('/getAuthUser').then((response)=>{
          vm.user = response.data
        })
        Vue.nextTick(()=>{
          vm.$http.get('/getShop/'+vm.user.id).then((response)=>{
            vm.shop = response.data.data.shop
          })
        })
      },
}
.....
```

`{{user.id}}` does work. where this gives me the following error:

> GET http://localhost:8000/getShop/undefined 404 (Not Found)

EDIT#1
if i do something like this it works but this should not be the right way to do in my opinion.

```
.....
methods:{
      getUserInfo(){
        var vm = this
        vm.$http.get('/getAuthUser').then((response)=>{
          vm.user = response.data
          vm.$http.get('/getShop/'+vm.user.id).then((response)=>{
            vm.shop = response.data.data.shop
          })
        })
      },
}
.....
```

EDIT#2
If I do something like this it wont work coz vm.user.id is not set.

```
.....
methods:{
      getUserInfo(){
        var vm = this
        vm.$http.get('/getAuthUser').then((response)=>{
          vm.user = response.data
        })
        vm.$http.get('/getShop/'+vm.user.id).then((response)=>{
          vm.shop = response.data.data.shop
        })
      },
}
.....
```

Comment: I think the other one is right way to do it, why do you think so?

Comment: But they offer nextTick for you to do it right? Why nextTick is not working?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think your understanding of what `nextTick` does is incorrect. If you read the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick), it says that the callback you pass to the `nextTick` function will be executed after the next DOM update.

Let's say you have a property that determines whether an element exists or not in the DOM with a [`v-if`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-if) directive. If you change the value of the property so that the element exists in the DOM, you might have to wait for Vue to process the change and update the DOM before you can grab a reference of that element, for example. In that case, you should use `Vue.nextTick` to make sure by the time you want to query the DOM to get that element, it actually exists.

Your scenario doesn't have anything to do with the DOM.

You have 2 asynchronous HTTP calls that you want to execute one after another, because the second relies on the result of the first. Your original implementation and third one (EDIT#2) are flaky because you don't make sure the first HTTP request is complete before firing the second one, which explains why you get errors about `vm.user.id` not being set.

Your second implementation (EDIT#1) is more correct because the second HTTP request is fired after the first one completes. Still, I'd suggest a minor modification:

```js
getUserInfo() {
    vm.$http.get('/getAuthUser')
        .then(response => {
            vm.user = response.data;

            return vm.$http.get('/getShop/' + vm.user.id);
        }).then(response => {
            vm.shop = response.data.data.shop;
        });
}
```

The first callback returns a `Promise` which result is fed into the second `then` call. I like this approach because it avois having nested `then`s. I would also suggest you to read the [MDN docs on Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: There is a thing that not sure about `nextTick`, if I put `nextTick` in a method and I put that method into life cycle `created()`, so the code inside `nextTick` will not be executed at the lifecycle `created` but instead will be executed at the next DOM update am I right?

Comment: Or the update on the DOM on limited on the method itself? or any update happens on the DOM next?

Comment: `nextTick`'s callback will be executed on the next DOM update after you called `nextTick`. I don't know the internals to tell you if DOM updates happen for each method or if they are somehow batched - that is, DOM updates from several methods could be applied in one go. I guess [this link](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue) is a good read if you want more details.

Comment: thanks for your further explanation. Lets have a look at the final example provided in your link. It seems to be the same with my original nextTick code to me. Once you set value, using nextTick the code will happens after the value is being set so that it works. But in my case it doesnt.

Comment: these examples are very different since the one mentioned in the documentation link is related to the DOM. In your case, it's not related to the DOM at all. You make a first HTTP request to get the user id, and the second HTTP request needs this user id to get other data. Nothing involves the DOM in that, so `nextTick` is not needed, and you have to wait until the first request is complete - i.e until you have the user id - to fire the second HTTP request

Comment: that makes perfect sense to me now. Thanks a lot for your long explanation

Comment: happy I could help ;-)